# FreePBX & Zoostorm

Tags: centos, freepbx

I'm having some issues trying to install the FreePBX Distro on a new Zoostorm box. 
It keeps asking me for drivers.

Here's the error message:

```
No Driver Found
Unable to find any service of the type needed for this installation type.
Would you like to manually select you driver or use a driver disk?
```

I've tried switching the HD mode in the BIOS from AHcI to IDE, but this does not help.

---

FreePBX Distro Stable-1.815.210.58

Zoostorm Manufacturer ID: 7873-1064

The motherboard is a Gigabyte Ultra Durable GA-H61M-S2PV

Processor Intel Core i5-2320 CPU 3.0GHz

Chipset Intel H61

Express Display N/A Graphics On-board integrated Intel graphics

Networking Realtek 10/100/1000

Comment: Could you provide a little more details on your hardware -- motherboard make/model?

Comment: The motherboard is a Gigabyte Ultra Durable GA-H61M-S2PV

Comment: @JayRozanski Please edit your question to include the relevant information ([nicely formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/)) - It looks like the Junior Jumble in my newspaper when you put it in the comments.  Thanks :-)

Comment: hows that? sorry about the mess before

Answer (score 0):

The "FreePBX Distro" is unfortunately a poor choice for new hardware, since it's based on CentOS 5 and won't have support for many new motherboards. This particular error occurs because the kernel doesn't have driver support for various parts of the motherboard hardware.

You would be best served by [installing it yourself](http://www.freepbx.org/support/documentation/installation) on a more recent distribution, such as CentOS 6 or Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. While this seems to take longer at the beginning, you learn more about how the system is put together and will be in a better position to actually maintain it.